# how to stop the side effect of React.useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, use-effect

as soon as I go on to route `/login`  in my web app it triggers an `useEffect` which it should not as no state has been changed at that point, please have a look at my code and tell me where am I wrong

```
function Login(){
const history = useHistory();

var [email, setEmail] = React.useState("");
var [password, setPassword] = React.useState("");
var [isLoggedIn, setLogin] = React.useState(false);
var [allTodosList, setList] = React.useState([]);

React.useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("triggered")
}, [isLoggedIn])

const sendLogin = async(event) => {
    try {
        var data = {
            Email : email,
            Password: password,
        }
        const response = await axios.post("/api/login", data);
        if (response.data.verified === true){
            const todoList = response.data.todos;
            setLogin(true);
        }
        else{
            alert("Invalid credentials please try again");
        }
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log("there is an error while sending login data via post");
        console.log(err);
    }
}
return(
    <div className = "login-form">
        <form>
            <input  
             type="text" className = "emailbox"
             placeholder = "Email" value = {email}
             onChange = {(event) => setEmail(event.target.value)}/>
            <input type="password" className = "passwordbox"
            name="password" id="password" 
            placeholder= "password" value = {password}
            onChange = {(event) => setPassword(event.target.value)}/>
            <span className = "login-button"><Button variant = "cantained"color = "secondary"
            onClick = {sendLogin}> Login</Button></span>
        </form>
    </div>
)
}
export default Login;
```

as I go on to this component using react route the useEffect gets triggered somehow and it console logs triggered..
please tell me how can I stop this useEffect from triggering unless the state is changed???

Comment: All hooks run on the initial render. The `useEffect` hook is no different. The callback will be called. If there is some logic you *don't* want to run on the initial render then you can use a ref to hold a value that is toggled true after the first render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It triggers on load and whenever the state changes. You should conditionally check the state.

```
React.useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("triggered")
    if (isLoggedIn) {
       console.log('isLoggedIn is true')
    }    
    //else, just don't do anything.

}, [isLoggedIn])
```

> If you’re familiar with React class lifecycle methods, you can think
> of useEffect Hook as componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate, and
> componentWillUnmount combined.
> https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Which explains why useEffect is called when component is mounted, updated (base on dependency or empty array - called only once), and will be unmounted (cleanup).

Comment: yes it will solve my problem , but i am just curious why is this happening

Comment: updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this example.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-eelqp2

I created a hook `useMountedRef` and check if mountedRef is true to avoid the side effect.

The reason why I used `setTimeout` is to make a reasonable delay so that we can make sure that the ref value is set to true after all initial useEffects.